# The report does not show the data to a particular user

Tags: custom-reports

I have a task report that shows tasks of employee X
And there is another employee Y who is unable to view this report
How can I give her permission.

Employee Y manages to view all reports except that
I believe this is a problem that she does not have permission to perhaps view and edit tasks that she has not created
The question is how to get around it.

Comment: Does Y have access to the folder containing the report?

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce  for Activity objects (Task & Event), there are only 2 option in the Organization-Wide Defaults sharing setting:

- Controlled by Parent
- Private

Private
Only activity owner (label as Assigned To), and users above the activity owner in the role hierarchy can edit and delete the activity.
Users with read access to the record to which the activity is associated (Name and Related To) can view and report on the activity.

Controlled by Parent
A user can perform an action (such as view, edit, transfer, and delete) on an activity based on whether he or she can perform that same action on the records associated with the activity.

We do not have other ways to provide the access. So Tasks will be private to everyone except Admins and anyone with Modify All (probably Read All too) if they aren't related to any object. They take on the sharing settings of the object they are related to.

Please refer [Link](https://www.simplysfdc.com/2015/01/salesforce-activity-controlled-by-parent.html) for more details.